# Remove Line Breaks and spaces From Json Object Keys typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Json object from Excel sheet conversion and it probably comes with some keys with
Line breaks and spaces I want a function to remove all line breaks and spaces from
json object keys
This is the structure of the json

```
 {"SOH":[{"MN":"asdf","Part\r\nNumber":"1234"},{"MN":"asdf2","Part\r\nNumber":"12343"}]}
```

expected outcome

```
 {"SOH":[{"MN":"asdf","PartNumber":"1234"},{"MN":"asdf2","PartNumber":"12343"}]}
```

Thanks for support

Comment: have you tried regexes : jsonText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""); ?

Comment: yes i use it and no change

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.entries()`, `map()` and `replace()` to recreate objects with replaced values.

```js
const obj = {
  "SOH": [
    { "MN": "asdf", "Part\r\nNumber": "1234" },
    { "MN": "asdf2", "Part\r\nNumber": "12343" }
  ]
};

const result = {
   "SOH": obj.SOH.map(o => {
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k.replace(/(\n|\s)/g, ""), v]));
   })
};
console.log(result);
```

Or if you want to make it more dynamic.

```js
const obj = {
   "SOH": [
      { "MN": "asdf", "Part\r\nNumber": "1234" },
      { "MN": "asdf2", "Part\r\nNumber": "12343" }
   ],
   "MOH": [
      { "MN": "asdf", "Part\r\nNumber": "1234" },
      { "MN": "asdf2", "Part\r\nNumber": "12343" }
   ],
   "KOH": [
      { "MN": "asdf", "Part\r\nNumber": "1234" },
      { "MN": "asdf2", "Part\r\nNumber": "12343" }
   ]
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
   return [k, v.map(x => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).map(([kk, vv]) => [kk.replace(/(\n|\s)/g, ""), vv])))]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with my in keys not value

Comment: You could change `Object.values` to `Object.keys`

Comment: This is the structure of the json object how to access the key         
 {"SOH":[{"MN":"asdf","Part\r\nNumber":"1234"},{"MN":"asdf2","Part\r\nNumber":"12343"}]}

Comment: I want to modify the key and the value remains the same

Comment: {"SOH":[{"MN":"asdf","PartNumber":"1234"},{"MN":"asdf2","PartNumber":"12343"}]}

Comment: @ABM this should do

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot